# Highlight tables cells based on values in JSON with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a web page which displays a table of information from a JSON. Once search is done the table cells change background color to match certain values returned in the jason file.

See sample in  **[JS Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4HF4B/2/)**

**My JSON and Jquery attempt**

```
  var data = [{
    "id": "1",
        "slot": "01",
        "date": "20-01-2014",
        "status": "1",
        "code": "2"
}, {
    "id": "41",
        "slot": "05",
        "date": "20-01-2014",
        "status": "0",
        "code": "1"
}, {
    "id": "11",
        "slot": "04",
        "date": "20-01-2014",
        "status": "0",
        "code": "4"
}, {
    "id": "5",
        "slot": "03",
        "date": "20-01-2014",
        "status": "0",
        "code": "1"
}, {
    "id": "23",
        "slot": "02",
        "date": "20-01-2014",
        "status": "1",
        "code": "3"
}];
$("button").click(function () {
    var $results = $("#results"), // Get the TR.
        $tds = $("#results").find("td"), // Get the TDs within the TR.
        noRecord = "<td colspan=\"5\">No record to display!</td>";


    // Check to see if data was returned.

    if (data === undefined) {
        // Data was not returned.

        if ($results.html().indexOf(noRecord) === -1) {
            // Results TR has previous values that need to be removed.

            for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            $($tds[i]).remove();

            // Add back the [No record to display!] TD.

            $(noRecord).insertAfter($tds[0]);
        }
    } else {
        // Data was returned.

        $.each(data, function (i) {
            // Store the current data.

            var st = parseInt(data[i].status,10);
            var sl = parseInt(data[i].slot,10);
            var cd = parseInt(data[i].code,10);

            // Check to see if the Results TR has previous values or not.

            if ($results.html().indexOf(noRecord) > -1) {
                // Results TR does not have previous values.

                var html = "";

                // Generate new TDs.

                for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                    if (st === 0 && i === sl) {
                        html += "<td class=\"noerror\"></td>";
                    } else if (st === 1 && i === sl) {
                        html += "<td class=\"error\"></td>";
                    }
                }

                // Remove [No record to display!] TD and replace with new TDs.

                $($tds[1]).replaceWith(html);
            } else {
                // Results TR has previous values so we need to loop 
                // through each existing TD replacing its class

                for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                    if (st !== 0) {
                        // Change class to "error"

                        $($tds[i])
                            .removeClass("noerror")
                            .addClass("error");

                    } else {
                        // Change class to "noerror" 

                        $($tds[i])
                            .removeClass("error")
                            .addClass("noerror");

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The HTML table is like

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Slot/statu-error</td>
        <td>Slot1</td>
        <td>Slot2</td>
        <td>Slot3</td>
        <td>Slot4</td>
        <td>Slot5</td>
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="results">
        <td>First row</td>
        <td colspan="5">No record to display!</td>
        <td>
            <button>More+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button>Update</button>
<p> <b>What I actually want on update</b><br />
    <i>The cell is green when stus is = 1, red otherwise <br />
        The cell is green when code = 1, red otherwise<br />
    Typically there will be more rows than shown for other parameters</i>
</p>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Slot/statu-error</td>
        <td>Slot1</td>
        <td>Slot2</td>
        <td>Slot3</td>
        <td>Slot4</td>
        <td>Slot5</td>
        <td>Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="results">
        <td>Status</td>
        <td class="noerror"></td>
        <td class="error"></td>
        <td class="error"></td>
        <td class="error"></td>
        <td class="noerror"></td>
        <td>
            <button>More+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td class="error"></td>
        <td class="noerror"></td>
        <td class="error"></td>
        <td class="noerror"></td>
        <td class="error"></td>
        <td>
            <button>More+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<button>Update</button>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? You may need to clarify what behaviour you are expecting.

Comment: I looked at your fiddle, but it has syntax errors preventing it from running.  I saw a missing semi-colon on line 34, and lines 58-60 should be data[i] instead of data.[i]  After that is started to complain about noRecord not being defined - I'm not sure where that was declared or what exactly it's supposed to represent.

Comment: I have added the missing variable. and corrected the data.[i] mistake

Comment: @DrydenLong Thanks for tour response if you look at the [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4HF4B/2/) I want to achieve the seond table from the first dynamically and asynchronously with Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but let me explain - [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4HF4B/4/).

So the code goes through the array as the primary source, parses the array, then distributes the green/red to the appropriate td (not in the order of the array).

JS

```
$("button").on('click', function (index) {

    $.each( data, function(index){
        var slotbox = data[index]['slot'];
        slotbox = +slotbox + 1;
        var statusbox = data[index]['status'];
        var codebox = data[index]['code'];
        if( +statusbox == 1 )
        {
          $('tr#status td:nth-child('+ slotbox +')' ).css('background-color', 'green');
         } else {
          $('tr#status td:nth-child('+ slotbox +')' ).css('background-color', 'red');
         }
        if( +codebox == 1 )
        {
          $('tr#code td:nth-child('+ slotbox +')' ).css('background-color', 'green');
         } else {
          $('tr#code td:nth-child('+ slotbox +')' ).css('background-color', 'red');
         }
                                   });//end each
                                          });//end click
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and insight. I still have a  prob. What if I have more that one data same slot as in [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4HF4B/5/)

Comment: Hmmm...that is more of a philosophical question for you. Which data point becomes more important? If you were to draw it out by hand, how would you make the selection?